# Rmarkdown flexdashboard valueboxes do not render properly in Chrome or IE (but work in FireFox)

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

My flexdashboard works perfectly in firefox but in chrome or IE, the valueboxes don't render properly and they get hidden behind other page elements. I've posted this on a few other sites but haven't been able to get an answer (sorry for this extra sentence, I'm getting an error saying I haven't provided enough detail and I don't know what else to add).

Here is a reprex of my code (and a pastebin in case this doesn't work well https://pastebin.pl/view/1d1503f4):

````html
---
title: "reprex"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: yeti
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    social: menu
    source: embed
---

<script>
$('.navbar-logo').wrap('<a href="http://www.website.com" target=blank>');
</script>


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(knitr) # for RMarkdown to HTML
library(rmarkdown) # to generate Rmd final document
library(shiny) # dashboard interactivity
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
======================================================================
some text for the sidebar

some more text

Section 1
======================================================================

## Row 1 {data-height=9}
-------------------------------

### valuebox1
```{r}
valueBox("986070", icon = "fa-user-times")
```

### valuebox2
```{r}
valueBox("8619681", icon = "fa-user-times")
```

## Row {data-height=800 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------------------------

### some other stuff

```{r}
# generate leaflet object, define basemap
leaflet(height = 400) %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", group = "CartoDB (Default)") %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap", group = "Esri") %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter", group = "CartoDB Dark") %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("CartoDB (Default)", "Esri", "CartoDB Dark"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
absolutePanel(
        draggable = FALSE, top = "2%", left = "5%", right = "auto", bottom = "auto",
        width = '30%', height = 'auto',
        style = "background: white; border:3px solid #eaf2f8; color: #5d6063; justify-content: center;",
        p(strong("some text"))
    )
```

random text
````

Showing in Firefox (on top) and Chrome/IE (on bottom):

[picture of dashboard in both browers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaLVQ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this myself by removing the `data-height=50` from the row containing the valueboxes. For anyone who comes across this error in the future. Chrome apparently interprets the CSS/HTML differently than Firefox. If anyone could provide input about why the occurs, I'd love to know.